# Connect raspberry pi to an iphone app without port forwarding

Tags: gpio, connection

For our capstone project, we have a python code that is supposed to detect the presence of a tile beacon, then we want that program to communicate with an iphone app built with swift letting it know that the tile is present.
We also want the app to be able to send back something, like maybe a command to scan again, or to turn on an LED on the GPIO
We cant use port forwarding because we are working in the university and will have to demo it there.
I thought about services like hamachi, but i am not sure if they are right foe this type of application.
Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: perhaps some sort of server that both the pi and the app can connect to that brokers messages between the two devices

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with https://remote.it. You just have to signup and install their deamon on your pi:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install connectd
sudo connectd_installer
```

Then use their APIs from the iPhone to initiate the connection.

```
curl -X POST \
     -H "token:$REMOTEIT_TOKEN" \
     -H "developerkey:$REMOTEIT_DEVELOPER_KEY" \
     -d '{"wait":"true","deviceaddress":"'$REMOTEIT_DEVICE_ADDRESS'"}' \
     https://api.remot3.it/apv/v27/device/connect
```

Their [docs site](https://docs.remote.it/api-reference/devices/connect) has some other language examples.